# How to set custom homepage via a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, templates

I am developing a plugin movie database plugin and i want set few custom templates to wordpress theme using the plugin. how can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out this post on: [How to create a custom home page via plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-custom-home-page-via-plugin), on wordpress.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the homepage template via plugin like this:

```
// Filter to replace the template of the home page
add_filter( 'template_include', 'replace_home_page' );

function replace_home_page( $template ) {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'new_template.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

[src/read more](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-custom-home-page-via-plugin)

Comment: there's also a [`front_page_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) filter which could simplify things a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback & referencing resources. It worked.